# How to simulate accordion click event to assert the displayed text

Tags: java, junit, wicket

I have in my page the following accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
 <div wicket:id="foo"></div>
<div wicket:id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Wehen someone clicks on `<div wicket:id="foo"></div>`, some text is displayed.
My Question is: How to simulate click event on this accordion link, sothat I can assert the displayed text with junit. I tried the following:

```
wicketTester.clickLink("foo");
```

But I get the following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Link foo is not a Link, AjaxLink, AjaxFallbackLink or AjaxSubmitLink
```

Comment: How do you populate the div when user clicks on it? Do you use an AJAX behavior?

Comment: @AndreaDelBene: Yes I use AJAX Behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at methods executeAjaxEvent and executeBehavior of wicketTester. I think that one of them can be used to simulate user's click on div.